# Angular, createComponent() throws "ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property"

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am creating components dynamically and I am passing the component's class via ngrx action and eventually have:

```
loadComponent(componentType: Type<any>): void {
  const viewContainerRef = this.contentHost.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  componentRef.instance.type = componentType;
}
```

As soon as this method is called I get:

```
core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property __NG_ELEMENT_ID__, object is not extensible
    at bloomAdd (core.js:3048)
    at diPublicInInjector (core.js:3190)
    at createRootComponentView (core.js:12159)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:24822)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:22896) <--- this is the createComponent()
    at WorkspaceSingleComponent.loadComponent (workspace-single.component.ts:45)  <---- this is my class
    at SafeSubscriber._next (workspace-single.component.ts:32)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently when this Component class passes thru the ngrx action's serialization it gets frozen and we cannot use it to construct new instances.

We can use the following workaround to make it working, until we find a better way. In app.module.ts, to your StoreModule's initializer add:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false,
        strictActionTypeUniqueness: isDevMode(),
        strictActionWithinNgZone: isDevMode(),
        strictStateImmutability: isDevMode(),
        strictStateSerializability: false,
      }
    }),
```

Thanks to Simon Hayden for this workaround. Source: https://gitter.im/ngrx/platform?at=5f3cbaa33dac53434017de6a

Comment: Could you not use something like an enum to pass with the action and then use a simple key value map to resolve for the class at the point of creation? Asked another way: what forces you to pass the class around with an Action? Just curious whats the use case here.

Comment: @Loop I could certainly use additional service and pass the component classes thru it but that just adds to it all. I want to minimize the usage of additional structures. Technically I pass "Type" around...  normally that is not a big deal.

Comment: Just had the experience that passing anything other than a pure object thru ngrx is rather tedious.

Comment: @Loop, I agree - it is tedious due to the serialization ngrx library applies. It is good that one can control how it is done (the serialization). I guess they made that this way to minimize the chance of breaking the immutability of the state objects..

Comment: What's with the anonymous downvote? if you have questions or comment just paste them here. @Stackoverflow.com should ask for comments on downvote.

Comment: This is not a viable solution.  Those rules are there to protect developers during the development process.  If you turn them off, you run the risk of introducing bugs into your production code.

Comment: @Barry As I mentioned it is a workaround. The proper thing to do is as Loop mentioned pass a key or something and access the complex structure directly on the other side of the action - therefore not pass any complex structures thru ngrx serialization